How should I invoke recursive make across ssh into a local vm?
Typically, I recurse normally:
recipe-X:
  $(MAKE) recipe-Y

However, on MacOS I recurse differently:
recipe-X:
ifeq ($(shell uname -s),Darwin)
  colima ssh -- make $@
else
  <recipe script>
endif

Should I use $(MAKE), or is this a case where I should really make?  I am not clear on the differences between the two modes in this context, and how they will interact.  My understanding is that $(MAKE) is a macro that propagates parallelism, environment and other concerns to the sub-make... but I am having some trouble.
What I have noticed is that $(MAKE) may break commands that would otherwise access the network within the vm by propagating the environment variables.  But I have not had success with the network-based commands using ordinary make..commands which do work when I ssh into the vm and invoke via the cli.
So before diving in and doing something too clever, I figured there might be a special way that make is expecting me to use it for this purpose.

$(MAKE) does three things:

It ensures that you're using the same binary in the submake as the parent (for example if the parent runs /my/special/make/bin/make but /my/special/make/bin is not on the PATH before /usr/bin, then using simple make to recurse would give the wrong make binary).
It tells make that the recipe should be invoked even if running in -n (don't build) mode.  You usually want this else your make -n doesn't tell you what will really be built.
It ensures that the sub-make receives the correct form of the MAKEFLAGS environment variable so it can participate in the jobserver (parallel build control) facility.

If you are going to run make on a remote system, then you definitely don't want #3 as the jobserver is local only: it is not network-aware.
It's not clear if you want #1 or not: that's up to you and your environment.  This is especially true on MacOS, which ships a very old and very broken version of GNU Make as it's "normal" version, which no one should ever use.
You also may or may not want #2, depending on what these recipes actually do, but you want this you can get the same behavior without using $(MAKE) if you prefix your recipe with +.
In short, you probably don't want to use $(MAKE) in this situation.  But you may have to do something to emulate the parts of it that you DO want.

what about variables I've exported within make, some of which may have been provided during my initial command -- do those go with ordinary make as well as the $(MAKE) invocation?

There is no difference on which variables are exported to any recipe, regardless of whether it contains $(MAKE) or any other value.  I listed the differences above, so if I didn't specify it there it doesn't behave differently :).
